# PHP mail() error; I can't see for looking!

Tags: php, html, email

I'm having an issue with a simple PHP mailer. I've had this script working, but it now doesn't work and I can't see for the life of me why not. It's instead spitting out the raw HTML rather than the rendered template.

If someone could have a browse and get back to me then that would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send']))
{
    // explode the email addresses
    $emails = explode(',', strtolower($_POST['to']));

    // validate each email address
    foreach ($emails as $id => $email) {
        if (!filter_var(trim($email), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            die($email . ' is not a valid email address');
        }
    }

    // all is good, let's send the emails out
    $subject = 'Digital Pop Christmas Email';
    $message = file_get_contents('index.html');

    // loop through each recipient
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        $to = $email;
        $subject = 'Merry Christmas from Digital Pop';
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: Digital Pop <info@digitalpop.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            echo "Email successfully sent to $email";
        } else {
            echo "Error sending email to $email";
        }
        echo "<br />\r\n";
    }
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>PHP Mailer</title>
    <meta http-equiv="author" content="martin@digitalpop.co.uk" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Send the <a href="./">Digital Pop Christmas Email</a>.</p>
    <form action="?" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <div><label for="to">To:</label> <small>(separate email addresses with commas)</small></div>
        <div><textarea name="to" id="to" cols="50" rows="8"></textarea></div>
        <div><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" /></div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The URL of the email is http://www.digitalpop.co.uk/xmas_email/ for those who wish to see what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: What do you mean by Raw HTML? Does it contain unparsed PHP code?

Comment: Yes. It spits out the headers after "MIME-Version: 1.0" and then the source of index.html.

Comment: I think he means his email isn't being recognize as formatted HTML, instead showing up as plain text.

Comment: why do you have two different `$subject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some rare cases due to a mail server misconfiguration you need only \n instead of \r\n
Try that out.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code (php file and index.html) and send my self a nice Merry Christmas mail :) 
It worked like a charm for me, so the problem is in either your server's config or maybe your mail client (I use GMail). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you mail logs? (usually in /var/log/mail.log). You might have been temporarily blocked if you've been sending too many emails in a short period (happens with Gmail).